# Android studio crashing after changing SDK to 12

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

so i tried changing my jdk from jdk8 to jdk12
and it's now crashing whenever i try to start it.

the

> sudo /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio

works for me when i try to launch my android studio
but then i dont work when i manually select android studio application
and it show this error:

```
nternal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:224)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.lambda$initApplication$0(IdeaApplication.java:77)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:313)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:348)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator'
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.handleComponentError(PluginManager.java:258)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.PlatformComponentManagerImpl.handleInitComponentError(PlatformComponentManagerImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:504)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$9(ApplicationImpl.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:532)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:151)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:405)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:391)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:217)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:157)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:76)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:82)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.<init>(AndroidSdkData.java:139)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:104)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:78)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:112)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkData.getSdkData(AndroidSdkData.java:119)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.parse(AndroidPlatform.java:86)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidSdkAdditionalData.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidSdkAdditionalData.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidPlatform.getInstance(AndroidPlatform.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getEligibleAndroidSdks(IdeSdks.java:600)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getFirstAndroidSdk(IdeSdks.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.sdk.IdeSdks.getAndroidSdkPath(IdeSdks.java:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.setupSdks(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:304)
    at com.android.tools.idea.startup.GradleSpecificInitializer.run(GradleSpecificInitializer.java:128)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.activateAndroidStudioInitializerExtensions(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:202)
    at com.android.tools.idea.AndroidInitialConfigurator.<init>(AndroidInitialConfigurator.java:71)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
    at org.picocontainer.defaults.InstantiatingComponentAdapter.newInstance(InstantiatingComponentAdapter.java:193)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.doGetComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:85)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.instantiateGuarded(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:62)
    at com.intellij.util.pico.CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(CachingConstructorInjectionComponentAdapter.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:462)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema PluginClassLoader[org.jetbrains.android, 10.3.4.2] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@71677abb
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:49)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 55 more
```

I tried reinstalling my android studio but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Know the compatibility of JDK for your version IntelliJ. Here is the link https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under 
Make sure your computer has the path for java. Try "java -version" in cmd to know your version. 
Try running with admin privilege.

Comment: How? i'm sorry i don't know